# My toy language's evaluator won't type check

Tags: haskell, gadt

Here's the code

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, TypeFamilies                     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables, OverloadedStrings  #-}
module Lib where

import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad.Except
import Control.Monad.State
import Data.Text

type Var = Text
type Store a = [(Var, Expr a)]
-- type EvalMonad a = ExceptT Text (State (Store a))

class (Num a, Eq a, Ord a) => Divisible a where
  divide :: a -> a -> a

instance Divisible Int where divide = div
instance Divisible Float where divide = (/)

data Expr a where
  BoolConst   ::  Bool -> Expr Bool
  NumberConst :: (Divisible n) => n -> Expr n
  SquanchyString :: Text -> Expr Text
  SquanchyVar :: Text -> Expr Text

  Not         :: Expr Bool -> Expr Bool
  Xor         :: Expr Bool -> Expr Bool -> Expr Bool

  Equals      :: (Eq a) => Expr a -> Expr a -> Expr Bool
  GreaterThan :: (Eq a) => Expr a -> Expr a -> Expr Bool

  Add         :: (Divisible n) => Expr n -> Expr n -> Expr n

eval :: Expr a -> ExceptT Text (State (Store a)) a
eval (BoolConst a)      = return a
eval (NumberConst a)    = return a 
eval (SquanchyString s) = return s

eval (SquanchyVar v) = extractValue v

eval (Not b)   = not <$> eval b
eval (Xor a b) = do
              orRes :: Bool <- (||) <$> eval a <*> eval b
              andRes :: Bool <- (&&) <$> eval a <*> eval b
              let notRes = not andRes
              return $ orRes && notRes

eval (Equals a b) = do -- This stanza is where the problem gets revealed
                      res :: Bool <- equals a b
                      return res
-- eval (GreaterThan a b) = (>) <$> eval a <*> eval b

eval (Add a b) = (+) <$> eval a <*> eval b
eval _             = undefined

equals :: (Eq n) => Expr n -> Expr n -> ExceptT Text (State (Store n)) Bool
equals a b = do
  eOne <- eval a
  eTwo <- eval b
  return $ eOne == eTwo

extractValue :: Text -> ExceptT Text (State (Store a)) a
extractValue v = do
    store :: Store a <- lift get
    case (lookup v store) of
      Just i -> eval i
      Nothing -> throwError "doh"
```

Here's the error

```
• Could not deduce: a1 ~ Bool
  from the context: a ~ Bool
    bound by a pattern with constructor:
               Equals :: forall a. Expr a -> Expr a -> Expr Bool,
             in an equation for ‘eval’
    at /home/michael/git/brokensquanchy/src/Lib.hs:65:7-16
  ‘a1’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    a pattern with constructor:
      Equals :: forall a. Expr a -> Expr a -> Expr Bool,
    in an equation for ‘eval’
    at /home/michael/git/brokensquanchy/src/Lib.hs:65:7-16
  Expected type: ExceptT Text (State (Store a)) Bool
    Actual type: ExceptT Text (State (Store a1)) Bool
• In a stmt of a 'do' block: res :: Bool <- equals a b
  In the expression:
    do res :: Bool <- equals a b
       return res
  In an equation for ‘eval’:
      eval (Equals a b)
        = do res :: Bool <- equals a b
             return res
• Relevant bindings include
    b :: Expr a1
      (bound at /home/michael/git/brokensquanchy/src/Lib.hs:65:16)
    a :: Expr a1
      (bound at /home/michael/git/brokensquanchy/src/Lib.hs:65:14)
   |
66 |                       res :: Bool <- equals a b
```

I'm hoping the answer is to include missing type information, but I'm not really sure. Any ideas?

Update: I improved my code, prompted by chepner's comment. But I still get the same error.

Why does ghc think `a` and `a1` are different? How can I convince it otherwise?

Comment: You've said that `equals` requires two arguments with `Eq` instances, but you don't ensure anywhere that an `Equals` value is constructed under the same constraint.

Comment: Those are not the same `a`. The `a` inside the `Equals` constructor is different from the `a` that is generic parameter of `eval`.

Comment: Imagine `eval (Equals (SquanchyVar "foo") (SquanchyVar "bar"))`. Here, the `a` inside the `Equals` constructor is `Text`, but the `a` that is generic parameter of `eval` is `Bool`.

Comment: I think a deeper problem is that your `eval` can only ever return one type. Because its result type `a` is also mentioned in the monad type under which `eval` works, it means in order to be in the same monad, any nested calls to `eval` must always return the same type as the outer `eval` that calls them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of your store is broken.  In particular, the return type of `eval` is:

```
ExceptT Text (State (Store a)) a
```

while the return type of `equals` is:

```
ExceptT Text (State (Store n)) Bool
```

These types can only unify (as they must, for the case `eval (Equals a b) = ...`) if `a` and `n` are both `Bool`, i.e., only if you are comparing the equality of two booleans, and that's clearly not what you want.

More generally, the type of your store `Store a` indirectly forces all expressions in your language to have the same type, even in programs that don't use any variables (because the `a` is part of the monad's type, and that type needs to stay the same throughout your program), so you've accidentally written an evaluator that can *either* evaluate `Bool` expressions *or* evaluate `Text` expressions *or* evaluate numeric expressions, but can never handle expressions of different types in a single program.

In your current language, you only support `Text` variables (via `SquanchyVar`), so a quick way to fix this is to change every occurrence of `Store a` or `Store n` to `Store Text`, and modify `extractValue` to always return a `Text` value.  So, the following typechecks:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs                 #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies          #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables   #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings     #-}
module Lib where

import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad.Except
import Control.Monad.State
import Data.Text

type Var = Text
type Store a = [(Var, Expr a)]
-- type EvalMonad a = ExceptT Text (State (Store a))

class (Num a, Eq a, Ord a) => Divisible a where
  divide :: a -> a -> a

instance Divisible Int where divide = div
instance Divisible Float where divide = (/)

data Expr a where
  BoolConst   ::  Bool -> Expr Bool
  NumberConst :: (Divisible n) => n -> Expr n
  SquanchyString :: Text -> Expr Text
  SquanchyVar :: Text -> Expr Text

  Not         :: Expr Bool -> Expr Bool
  And         :: Expr Bool -> Expr Bool -> Expr Bool
  Or          :: Expr Bool -> Expr Bool -> Expr Bool
  Xor         :: Expr Bool -> Expr Bool -> Expr Bool

  Equals      :: (Eq a) => Expr a -> Expr a -> Expr Bool

  GreaterThan :: (Eq a) => Expr a -> Expr a -> Expr Bool

  LessThan    :: (Eq a) => Expr a -> Expr a -> Expr Bool

  Div         :: (Divisible n) => Expr n -> Expr n -> Expr n

  Mul         :: (Divisible n) => Expr n -> Expr n -> Expr n

  Sub         :: (Divisible n) => Expr n -> Expr n -> Expr n

  Add         :: (Divisible n) => Expr n -> Expr n -> Expr n

eval :: Expr a -> ExceptT Text (State (Store Text)) a
eval (BoolConst a)      = return a
eval (NumberConst a)    = return a
eval (SquanchyString s) = return s

eval (SquanchyVar v) = extractValue v

eval (Not b)   = not <$> eval b
eval (And a b) = (&&) <$> eval a <*> eval b
eval (Or a b)  = (||) <$> eval a <*> eval b
eval (Xor a b) = do
              orRes :: Bool <- (||) <$> eval a <*> eval b
              andRes :: Bool <- (&&) <$> eval a <*> eval b
              let notRes = not andRes
              return $ orRes && notRes

eval (Equals a b) = do -- This stanza is where the problem gets revealed
                      res :: Bool <- equals a b
                      return res
-- eval (GreaterThan a b) = (>) <$> eval a <*> eval b
-- eval (LessThan a b)    = (<) <$> eval a <*> eval b

eval (Div a b) = divide <$> eval a <*> eval b
eval (Mul a b) = (*) <$> eval a <*> eval b
eval (Add a b) = (+) <$> eval a <*> eval b
eval (Sub a b) = (-) <$> eval a <*> eval b
eval _             = undefined

equals :: (Eq n) => Expr n -> Expr n -> ExceptT Text (State (Store Text)) Bool
equals a b = do
  eOne <- eval a
  eTwo <- eval b
  return $ eOne == eTwo

extractValue :: Text -> ExceptT Text (State (Store Text)) Text
extractValue v = do
    store :: Store a <- lift get
    case (lookup v store) of
      Just i -> eval i
      Nothing -> throwError "doh"
```

Fixing your language to support variables with multiple types is significantly more complicated.

Comment: "In your current language, you only support Text variables (via SquanchyVar), so a quick way to fix this is to change every occurrence of Store a or Store n to Store Text " . I regret being so lazy there, as that is not my intent at all. I was writing placeholder code. I'm figuring out how to do variables better.

Answer (score 0):

Those are not the same `a`. The `a` inside the Equals constructor is different from the `a` that is generic parameter of `eval`.

Imagine this:

```
eval (Equals (SquanchyVar "foo") (SquanchyVar "bar"))
```

Here, the `a` inside the `Equals` constructor is `Text` (because that's the type of `SquanchyVar`), but the `a` that is generic parameter of `eval` is `Bool` (because that is the type of `Equals`). So they're different.

But a deeper problem is that your `eval` can only ever return one type. Because its result type `a` is also mentioned in the monad type `ExceptT Text (State (Store a))` under which `eval` works, it means that in order to be in the same monad, any nested calls to `eval` must always return the same type as the outer `eval` that calls them.

But wait! Does your monad actually *need* to mention `a`? Let's see where it's actually used. Looks like the only use site is in `extractValue`. And look: it doesn't actually extract value of *any* type, it's only ever expected to work with `Text`.

So that's the solution: just make your monad `ExceptT Text (State (Store Text))` instead of `ExceptT Text (State (Store a))`.

```
eval :: Expr a -> ExceptT Text (State (Store Text)) a

...

equals :: (Eq n) => Expr n -> Expr n -> ExceptT Text (State (Store Text)) Bool

...

extractValue :: Text -> ExceptT Text (State (Store Text)) Text
```